# Can I have a SVG Pattern with background color?

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I have SVG Polygons and for some polygons I use a pattern as fill. But I want a background color to that pattern. Like a pattern over a background color.

```
var pattern = me.canvas.append('defs')
    .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'diagonalHatch')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 4)
    .attr('height', 4)
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2')
    .attr('stroke', '#010101')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr("opacity",0.5);


var polyObj = polygonLayer.append("polygon")
        .attr('stroke','black')
        .attr('stroke-width','2')
        .style('fill','url(#diagonalHatch)');
```

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7vvbjth/7/). I want a color behind this pattern.

Please help.

Comment: Why not add a 4x4 `rect` also into the pattern and give it the required fill color?

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/g7vvbjth/8/)

Comment: @Harry Thanks for quick reply. Can you please edit my fiddle or create a new one to showcase this change.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g7vvbjth/10/) it is @Harshal. On further thinking, Matthias' answer would also be a good idea.

Comment: @SiddP - Yes but I don't to give backgroung-color to whole svg. I want that background color limited to that polygon.

Comment: Then have a look at Matthias's answer below I think that answers your question.

Comment: @Harry I did same changes but now pattern is not visible. http://jsfiddle.net/ydpp0719/2/.
My requirement is when a polygon with pattern is intersecting with polygon with no pattern, polygon with pattern should be given preference and should be visible fully and thats showing correctly in my fiddle. Only problem is pattern is not visible

Comment: You didn't modify the selector for the diagonalHatch pattern (line no: 19). Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ydpp0719/3/).

Comment: Thanks a lot Harry....worked

Comment: Do you want me to post that as an answer? Or, is Matthias' answer good enough for you?

Comment: You post answer. I am not using Matthias' way as it will require some changes in my code to draw one extra polygon and will be difficult for me to manipulate those. Yours is more simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I had mentioned in my comment, one way would be to add a 4x4 `rect` inside the `pattern` (before the `path`) and then give the `rect` the required fill.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <div id='myDiv'></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = d3.select('#myDiv')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', '400px')
      .attr('height', '400px');

    canvas.append('defs')
      .append('pattern')
      .attr('id', 'diagonalHatch')
      .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
      .attr('width', 4)
      .attr('height', 4)
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', 4)
      .attr('height', 4)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('fill', 'blue');

    d3.select('#myDiv svg pattern#diagonalHatch').append('path')
      .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2')
      .attr('stroke', '#010101')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1)
      .attr("opacity", 0.5);



    var polygon = canvas.append('polygon')
      .attr('fill', 'none').attr('points', '282.0000915527344,104,280.0001220703125,165.00009155273438,349,174.99998474121094,345.00006103515625,105.99999237060547,282.0000915527344,104')
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('stroke-width', '2')
      .style('fill', 'url(#diagonalHatch)')
  </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
```

---

Below is a demo with your actual code:

```css
/* map menu controls */

.ui-active rect {
  fill: #212121
}
.ui-active text {
  fill: #fff
}
.ui-default rect {
  fill: #e6e6e6
}
.ui-default text {
  fill: #000
}
.map-controls {
  display: none;
}
/* heatmap colors (courtesy of colorbrewer2.org) */

.RdYlBu .d6-6 {
  fill: #D73027;
  background: #D73027;
  color: #121212
}
.RdYlBu .d6-5 {
  fill: #FC8D59;
  background: #FC8D59;
  color: #121212
}
.RdYlBu .d6-4 {
  fill: #FEE090;
  background: #FEE090;
  color: #121212
}
.RdYlBu .d6-3 {
  fill: #E0F3F8;
  background: #E0F3F8;
  color: #121212
}
.RdYlBu .d6-2 {
  fill: #91BFDB;
  background: #91BFDB;
  color: #121212
}
.RdYlBu .d6-1 {
  fill: #4575B4;
  background: #4575B4;
  color: #121212
}
/* overlays */

.polygon {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill-opacity: 0.2
}
.vertex {
  stroke: lime;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  fill: none
}
/* vector field */

.vector {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: lightsteelblue
}
/* path plot */

.pathplot path {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: steelblue;
  fill: #E0E0E0;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.planned {
  stroke-dasharray: 9, 5
}
/* Grid lines*/

.grid .tick line {
  stroke: #e3e3e3;
  opacity: 1;
}
.pathplot line {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-dasharray: 15, 5;
}
.overlays line {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke: steelblue
}
.overlays path {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: steelblue;
  fill: none
}
.heatmap .d0 {
  fill: #D73027;
  stroke: null;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.heatmap .d1 {
  fill: #FC8D59;
  stroke: null;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.heatmap .d2 {
  fill: #FEE090;
  ;
  stroke: null;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.heatmap .d3 {
  fill: #E0F3F8;
  ;
  stroke: null;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.heatmap .d4 {
  fill: #91BFDB;
  ;
  stroke: null;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.heatmap .d5 {
  fill: #4575B4;
  ;
  stroke: null;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.overlays .PERIMETER {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-dasharray: 10, 2;
}
/*wall types*/

.overlays .cubicle {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #2F6299
}
.overlays .bookshelf {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #86471E
}
.overlays .brickwall {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke: #FF0000;
}
.overlays .drywall {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #948A54;
}
.overlays .thindoor {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #E36C0A;
}
.overlays .thickdoor {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: #E36C0A;
}
.overlays .concrete {
  stroke-width: 4px;
  stroke: #A9ABAA;
}
.overlays .elevatorshaft {
  stroke-width: 6px;
  stroke: #262626;
}
.overlays .thinwindow {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke: #FFC000;
}
.overlays .thickwindow {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: #FFC000;
}
.overlays .wrap {
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-opacity: 0;
}
.hmbands {} .hideBands {
  display: none !important;
}
.selector_radius {
  fill: transparent;
}
.selector_radius.selected {
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 3, 2;
}
.coverage_radius {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 3, 2
}
.coverage_radius.selected {
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 5, 4;
}
.background-floorplan {
  opacity: 0.15;
}
.heatmap {
  opacity: 0.25
}
svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
svg .grid .tick {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
svg text {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.mainDrawingPage {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
svg text::selection {
  background: none;
}
.axis path {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
.axis .axis-line {
  fill: solid;
  stroke: black;
}
/* Tooltip */

.nvtooltip,
.nvtooltip * {
  font-family: tahoma, arial, verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
.nvtooltip .missing {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.nvtooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 100000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.nvtooltip h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
}
.nvtooltip p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.apLabelText {
  /*font-weight: bold !important; */
  font-size: 10px;
}
.xAxesDivCls {
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden
}
.yAxesDivCls {
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 500px;
  /* overflow:hidden; */
  position: relative;
  top: -352px
}
.canvasDivCls {
  /* max-height:370px; */
  /* max-width:480px; */
  /* overflow:auto; */
  position: relative;
  top: -702px
}
.addImageBtnCls {
  position: relative;
  top: -700px;
  left: 250px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function appendPolygon() {
    debugger;
    var canvas = d3.select('.fp-overlays-1419951398667');

    canvas.append('defs')
      .append('pattern')
      .attr('id', 'diagonalHatch')
      .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
      .attr('width', 4)
      .attr('height', 4)
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', 4)
      .attr('height', 4)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('x', 0)
      .attr('fill', 'white');

    d3.select('svg pattern#diagonalHatch').append('path')
      .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2')
      .attr('stroke', '#010101')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1)
      .attr("opacity", 0.5);



    var polygon = canvas.append('polygon')
      .attr('fill', 'none').attr('points', '282.0000915527344,104,280.0001220703125,165.00009155273438,349,174.99998474121094,345.00006103515625,105.99999237060547,282.0000915527344,104')
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('stroke-width', '2')
      .style('fill', 'url(#diagonalHatch)')
  }
</script>

<body>
  <div id='xAxesDiv' class="xAxesDivCls">
    <svg height="500px" width="700px">
      <g class="x axis" transform="translate(100,50)">
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line y2="-6" x2="0"></line>
          <text y="-9" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;">0</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(72.60000000000001,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line y2="-6" x2="0"></line>
          <text y="-9" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;">100</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(145.20000000000002,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line y2="-6" x2="0"></line>
          <text y="-9" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;">200</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(217.79999999999998,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line y2="-6" x2="0"></line>
          <text y="-9" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;">300</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(290.40000000000003,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line y2="-6" x2="0"></line>
          <text y="-9" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;">400</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(363,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line y2="-6" x2="0"></line>
          <text y="-9" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;">500</text>
        </g>
        <path class="domain" d="M0,-6V0H363V-6"></path>
        <line x1="-70" class="axis-line" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"></line>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id='yAxesDiv' class="yAxesDivCls">
    <svg height="500px" width="700px">
      <g class="y axis" transform="translate(50,100)">
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
          <text x="-9" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">0</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,72)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
          <text x="-9" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">100</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,144)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
          <text x="-9" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">200</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,216)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
          <text x="-9" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">300</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,288)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
          <text x="-9" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">400</text>
        </g>
        <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,360)" style="opacity: 1;">
          <line x2="-6" y2="0"></line>
          <text x="-9" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">500</text>
        </g>
        <path class="domain" d="M-6,0H0V360H-6"></path>
        <text x="-25" y="-60" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-anchor: middle;">F</text>
        <line x1="0" class="axis-line" y1="-70" x2="0" y2="0"></line>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id='canvasDiv' class="canvasDivCls">
    <svg height="500px" width="650px">
      <g class="map-layers" width="363" height="360" x="0" y="0">
        <rect class="canvas" pointer-events="all" style="opacity: 0;"></rect>
        <g class="maplayer gridAxisLayer">
          <g class="fp-gridAxisLayer-1419951398667">
            <g class="grid" transform="translate(100,100)">
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line y2="360" x2="0"></line>
                <text y="-3" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(72.60000000000001,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line y2="360" x2="0"></line>
                <text y="-3" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(145.20000000000002,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line y2="360" x2="0"></line>
                <text y="-3" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(217.79999999999998,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line y2="360" x2="0"></line>
                <text y="-3" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(290.40000000000003,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line y2="360" x2="0"></line>
                <text y="-3" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(363,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line y2="360" x2="0"></line>
                <text y="-3" x="0" dy="0em" style="text-anchor: middle;"></text>
              </g>
              <path class="domain" d="M0,0V0H363V0"></path>
            </g>
            <g class="grid" transform="translate(100,100)">
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,0)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x2="363" y2="0"></line>
                <text x="-3" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,72)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x2="363" y2="0"></line>
                <text x="-3" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,144)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x2="363" y2="0"></line>
                <text x="-3" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,216)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x2="363" y2="0"></line>
                <text x="-3" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,288)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x2="363" y2="0"></line>
                <text x="-3" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text>
              </g>
              <g class="tick" transform="translate(0,360)" style="opacity: 1;">
                <line x2="363" y2="0"></line>
                <text x="-3" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;"></text>
              </g>
              <path class="domain" d="M0,0H0V360H0"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>

        <g class="maplayer overlays">
          <g class="fp-overlays-1419951398667">
            <g id="perimeterLayerId">
            </g>

          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <script>
    appendPolygon();
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if this is, what you actually mean, but I just added another polygon behind the one with the pattern (with the same coordinates) and filled it with a color. Just check out the fiddle below:

```
var bgPoly = canvas.append('polygon')
    .style('fill', '#ff9900')
    .attr('points','282.0000915527344,104,280.0001220703125,165.00009155273438,349,174.99998474121094,345.00006103515625,105.99999237060547,282.0000915527344,104')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7vvbjth/9/